# ESC/POS commands for printer module

Tags: c, printing, arduino, pos, escpos

I am trying to parse some commands to a printer module. it is extracted from a POS machine and I have driven that using Arduino as my CPU to pass image's HEX data to it. now I want to print text. I have found out that there is a universal command set called ESC/POS. but it seems like these commands are already installed on the commercial POS machines available in the market but not on the printer modules themselves. the module that I am using is [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=ltpz245&rlz=1C1GCEA_enIR879IR879&sxsrf=ACYBGNREkT_r_-Pya8FFl2GaqBk5Z6XIsg:1579595267447&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi0jbj2opTnAhUBcBQKHUliCoYQ_AUoAXoECAsQAw&biw=1821&bih=833#imgrc=hy218uX-2G0OTM:)

can anyone tell me how to install ESC/POS commands for my setup? here you can see the block diagram of my setup:[image]

Answer (score 0):

As with the previous question, the search results you have shown are only the mechanical units of the printer, no control units there.

Normally, a printer has a control unit that interprets the commands received and performs printing.

If you want to connect the Arduino directly to the mechanical unit of the printer, you have to implement all the functions included in the control unit with the Arduino.

It is a system specific to the mechanical unit used, and there will be no universal and free software.

In other words, it is necessary to create all the interpretation and implementation of ESC/POS commands and the control of the mechanical unit by scratch.

If that is what you want to do, do your best.

Here's an article that does something similar to you. It doesn't seem to be resolved.
[Print problem](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=630872.0)
This article includes the data sheet of the mechanical unit used by the questioner.
[LTPZ245-B_J.pdf](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?action=dlattach;topic=630872.0;attach=320038)
If you really want to use this topology, this datasheet will be useful.

[SII Thermal Printer Product Catalog 2018-2019](https://www.sii-ps.com/download/pdf/2018_thermal_printer_E.pdf)
Usually, use the control board(IFD501-01UK/IFD501-01SK) as shown on page 5 of this catalog.
If this is the case, contact SII and we will provide you with a printer driver for Linux.
I don't know if it can be used with Arduino.
Or, even without a device driver, a serial port control board(IFD501-01SK) would make it easy to connect and communicate with the Arduino.

Comment: Dear Kunif

thanks for your precious reply. yes I want to implement all the ESC/POS commands by scratch!(I don't think I can do otherwise!) 
one question, by the "control unit" you mean the CPU? as in this case is the microcontroller or I'm wrong?
and what do you mean by :

> It is a system specific to the mechanical unit used, and there will be
> no universal and free software.

Comment: It is the circuit board that contains the CPU. [IFD501-01SK](https://sii-thermalprinters.com/thermal-printers/ltp-and-capd-series/ifd501-01sk/)

Comment: They need to create data structures and control programs specific to the individual hardware, and they will not be standardized. And because it is an industrial program, it is usually private and protected by intellectual property rights.